# Record line in and speakers without Stereo Mix?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, speakers

On Windows 8.1, I'd like to record from my Line In input and my Speakers at the same time.

I understand this can be done with Stereo Mix. However, the volume is too low.

Is there a way to fix that, or an alternative way of mixing the inputs (other than running a cable)?

I'd prefer not to have to shell out money.

Comment: Perhaps explaining what the end goal is would help us put together a better answer. Right now it sounds as though your question is a bit close to a shopping recommendation. What, precisely, are you trying to record, and what have you tried so far to amplify the Stereo Mix output?

Comment: I have tried this and found that under Win8.1 it doesn't work.  So I ended up using an external mixer.

Comment: @music2myear I'm trying to record audio through the Line In input. I'm using a Realtek audio card and tried changing the volume settings in Relatek HD Audio Manager. didn't help.